How to pass the selected value of select2 element as parameter in htmx?
I want to do GET request with query parameter. However, the query parameter need to be taken from select2 elements. How do I pass the selected value of select2 to htmx?
Below is the simplified overview of my code.
<select id="filter">...</select>
<select id="filter2">...</select>
...
<button hx-get="{% url 'filter-data'}" hx-trigger="click" hx-include="#filter, #filter2" hx-target="targetDiv" >Filter</button>



<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#filter').select2()
    $('#filter2').select2()
}
</script>

I've tried to search for similar problem but none were found. Any pointer is appreciated.

Silly me, the param wasn't included because the select element was missing the name attribute. Adding them solves the problem.
Below solves the issue
<select id="filter" name="filter">...</select>
<select id="filter2" name="filter2">...</select>
...
<button hx-get="{% url 'filter-data'}" hx-trigger="click" hx-include="#filter, #filter2" hx-target="targetDiv" >Filter</button>



<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#filter').select2()
    $('#filter2').select2()
}
</script>


